# return the name of a sorted value in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have values like

```
amity = 0
erudite = 2
```

etc.

And I am able to sort the integers with

```
 print (sorted([amity, abnegation, candor, erudite, dauntless]))`
```

but I want the variable names to be attached to the integers as well, so that when the numbers are sorted I can tell what each number means.
Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Then put them in a dictionary. You cannot get `'erudite'` from its value.

Comment: What have you tried so far? [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=dictionary#dictionaries) is a good idea for this.

Answer (score 4):

Define a **mapping** between the names and the numbers:

```
numbers = dict(dauntless=42, amity=0, abnegation=1, candor=4, erudite=2)
```

Then **sort**:

```
d = sorted(numbers.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])
print(d)
# [('amity', 0), ('abnegation', 1), ('erudite', 2), ('candor', 4), ('dauntless', 42)]
```

To keep the result as a mapping/dictionary, call [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) on the sorted list:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

print(OrderedDict(d))
# OrderedDict([('amity', 0), ('abnegation', 1), ('erudite', 2), ('candor', 4), ('dauntless', 42)])
```

Comment: To add more variables, use `numbers.update(newname=1)`

Answer (score 0):

Python has a built in data-type called `dictionary`, it is used to map key, value pairs. It is pretty much what you asked for in your question, to attach a `value` into a specific `key`.

You can read a bit more about dictionaries [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

What I think you should do is to create a dictionary and map the names of the variables as strings to each of their integer values as shown below:

```
amity = 0
erudite = 2
abnegation = 50
dauntless = 10
lista = [amity, erudite, abnegation, dauntless]
dictonary = {} # initialize dictionary
dictionary[amity] = 'amity'# You're mapping the value 0 to the string amity, not the variable amity in this case.
dictionary[abnegation] = 'abnegation'
dictionary[erudite] = 'erudite'
dictionary[dauntless] = 'dauntless'
print(dictionary) # prints all key, value pairs in the dictionary
print(dictionary[0]) # outputs amity.
for item in sorted(lista):
    print(dictionary[x]) # prints values of dictionary in an ordered manner.
```